# User Select and Crop UIImageView

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

Hey guys,
I have a little issue here. I need my users to be able to select 4 different points in an image, and then, based on those points, draw a rectangle and crop the image to that rectangle.

Now, I've tried the method in UIImagePickerView that let's you edit the image, but I find it's very limited, and isn't exactly perfect for my needs.

I think I'd be able to handle the cropping to the rectangle part, since there seems to be lots of documentation on the internet about that. But after searching, I still can't find a good way for a user to draw a rectangle (or a shape, for that matter) on a UIImageView.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you implement your own view (subclass of *UIView*) that draws a rectangle based on the user's touches and gestures. Except for the rectangle outline, it should be transparent so it can be used as an overlay of the *UIImageView*.

Your view class mainly implements/overrides *drawRect:*. This is where you draw the rectangle.

Comment: OK cool thank you very much. Do you know of any place there's a tutorial or something I could find to help me?